# Does ubuntu require antivirus

Tags: security, antivirus, malware

Does ubuntu require antivirus? If yes then please tell me what's the difference between windows virus and ubuntu virus?

Comment: If you have any windows machines behind your ubuntu system: yes it might be handy. Ubuntu itself has no need at all for an antivirus. There are no virusses in the wild regarding Linux. Other types of malware yes but not virusses.

Answer (score 1):

There are viruses for Ubuntu but they are so rare to encounter since most viruses are targeted at Windows.If you are still not trusting try some antiviruses for Linux like AVG Free or others.Hers a link for reference:

[Linux Viruses](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-operating-system-is-virus-free)